# Using JQuery how can I detect a click on any html list element of a certain list and also get the text within the li element?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Using JQuery how can I detect a click on any html list element of a certain list and also get the text within the li element?

For example I have the following list:

```
<ul id="mylist">
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>        
</ul>
```

For example, if the user clicks on li element *one* then JQuery should detect this and also grab the string *"one"*.

## What I have done to try to solve the problem myself

I was thinking of giving each li element an id that began the same for example:

```
<li id='li-1'>one</li>
<li id='li-2'>two</li>
<li id='li-3'>three</li>
```

then doing the following (CoffeScript):

```
$('[id^="li-"]').click ->
  console.log $(this).html # should log one when user clicks on li-1 etc
```

But this seems really inelegant and messy. Please could someone help me and teach me a better way to do this (and one that works, as my example doesn't work :( )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Will this work? (with a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Xyh2m/))

```
$('#mylist li').on('click', function() {
    console.log($(this).html());
});
```

Here the event is attached to all `li` elements inside the `ul` which as an id of "mylist", so this won't fire on any other `li` in your dom.  Because the the event listener is attached to the `li` directly, calling `$(this)` gives you that element.

Or in CoffeeScript (and a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UB9fu/))

```
$('#mylist li').click ->
  console.log $(this).html()
  false
```